# Erro ao fazer reverse:

Tags: python

no eat.txt existe o seguinte conteudo:

```
02:26:31 14:44:45 09:53:27
14:17:35 12:33:44 09:30:12
```

Estou invertendo a ordem dos elementos ad seguinte maneira:

```
import sys

with open 'eat.txt as f:
    lines = f.read().strip().splitlines()

for line in lines:
    out = ' '.join(sorted(line.split(), reverse=True))
    print(out)
```

Saida:

```
14:44:45 09:53:27 02:26:31
14:17:35 12:33:44 09:30:12
```

Por que ele só troca a primeira linha e a segunda não?

Comment: Simples: porque a segunda linha já está ordenada na ordem inversa. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você observar, a segunda linha já está ordenada inversamente. Por isso aparenta que não aconteceu nada.